# QML - size limit for Courier font family

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

I'm playing with font size in `Text`/`TextInput`/`TextField` in QML.

For `Text` with `font.family: "MS Shell Dlg 2"` everything works as expected.
The funny thing happens when I try to use "Courier" family (I want monospace font): not every font size is shown and for `font.pointSize > ~20` displayed text stops growing. I tried to use `font.pixelSize` but effect is exactly the same.

**Is it normal behavior for Courier font in QML?**

Below is `Text` element used to test the behavior:

```
     Text {
        id: element
        x: 10
        y: 10
        text: qsTr("FF")
        font.pointSize: 40
        font.family: "Courier" //if "MS Shell Dlg 2" used everything is ok
    }
```

**Edit:
Font size works fine for "Courier New" family... While my immediate problem is solved, I'd really like to understand what's happening for "Courier" family.**

**Edit 2:
From discussion below seems like it's problem specific to my machine as other people say it works for them...**

**Edit 3:
My environment: Qt 5.14.2 on Windows 10 machine. I'm using QtCreator 4.11.2 and mingw 64bit compiler.**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe due to some container for your `Text` element?

This code is working for example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Row {
        id: buttonRow
        spacing: 5
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.left: parent.left
        width: parent.width

        Text {
            id: element
            x: 10
            y: 10
            text: qsTr("FF")
            font.pointSize: 140
            font.family: "Courier"
        }

        Button {
            id: button1
            text: "Click me"
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            onClicked: {
                element.font.pointSize = element.font.pointSize + 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's possible. I'll check it out in a moment. However, if that's the case why would "Courier New" and "MS Shell Dlg 2" work in the same conditions?

Comment: I checked it out: copied your code into my `main.qml`. The same effect. As you say that the above snippet works on your machine it seems the problem is something specific to my system...

Comment: @Lehu I'm using Qt 5.9 in a linux environment.

Comment: Qt 5.14 in Windows 10. That could have something to do with the behavior.

Comment: Just for testing, you could load your font using https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontloader.html

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. BUT! I've checked in MS Word: I can't even choose "Courier", only "Courier New". Maybe it's just that "Courier" on my system is defined up to ~20 and that's all?

Comment: Sounds like Courier is an older bitmap font so it can only be displayed at sizes the font supports. "New" is a scalable font which can be displayed at any size.